# How do you turn a string that looks like a List of Dictionaries into a List of Dictionaries?

Tags: c#

I have a string that looks like a List of Dictionaries:

```
string foo =  "\"[{ \"Key\":\"Value\", \"Key2\":\"Value\"}]\"";
```

How do I actually turn this into a list of dictionaries?

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> bar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you string seems to be json, you could use this:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;

(...)

string foo = "\"[{ \"Key\":\"Value\", \"Key2\":\"Value\"}]\"";

// Remove start and end quotes
var json = foo.Substring(1, foo.Length - 2);

var dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string,string>>>(json);
```

Comment: Don't tamper with the poor JSON like that, it's not necessary :)

Comment: @Jimi Look closer, it appears to be quoted JSON. Very odd.

Comment: @Ian Mercer I saw it, I supposed it was from a copy/paste from the debugger visualizer (the OP, not knowing it's a JSON response, may have added it to a string). But I may be wrong. I don't know what would send it like that.

Comment: @Ian Mercer I mean, not just the double-double-quotes, also the escapes. This looks like a double conversion.